# Iteration through a list of strings generates a TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings ['man', 'woman', 'child', 'teacher']. Based on some condition, I would like to set up color for nodes in a network.

```
for i in len(my_list):
    print(i)
    color_list[i]=colors_top[2]
```

where `colors_top` is `colors_top=['tab:orange','tab:blue','tab:green','lightsteelblue']`,  `color_list` is

```
['lightsteelblue',
 'lightsteelblue',...] *50
```

and

```
my_list is ['man', 'woman', 'child', 'teacher'].
```

I get the same error even when I run the following piece of code:

```
for i in range(50):
  if list_1[i] not in my_list:
    color_list[list_1[i]]=colors_top[0]
  if list_2[i] not in my_list:
    color_list[list_2[i]]=colors_top[1]
```

where `list_1` is `['man', 'woman', 'child', 'teacher','driver','student']` and `list_2` is `['driver', 'musician', 'man']`.

The error in both cases is a TypeError:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-2171da328686> in <module>
      1 for i in range(50):
      2   if list_1[i] not in my_list:
----> 3     color_list[list_1[i]]=colors_top[0]
      4   if list_2[i] not in my_list:
      5     color_list[list_2[i]]=colors_top[1]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

EDIT:

The logic is the following:

```
for i in range(50):
      print(list_1[i]) # e.g., professor
      print(my_list) #  ['man', 'woman', 'child', 'teacher']
      if list_1[i] not in my_list: # professor is not in the list my_list
        color_list[list_1[i]]=colors_top[0] # assign to professor the color orange
      if list_2[i] not in my_list: # e.g., driver
        color_list[list_2[i]]=colors_top[1] # assign blue
```

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious? `list_1[i]` is a string (e.g. `"man"`) and `color_list[list_1[i]]` is `color_list["man"]` which doesn't make any sense for a `list`. By the way we don't even see what `color_list` is in your question, please post a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: updated the question. My apologies  as I forgot to include it. I think there should be almost all the fields. The length of lists might be  different